# Ember mismatch names in index.js and package.json

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have two different names in my `package.json` and `index.js` which i cannot change on both places. I am getting this error.

> `ember-cli: Your names in package.json and index.js should match. The addon in /Users/nrehman/Projects/copilot-seo-score currently have '@copilot/copilot-seo-score' in package.json and 'copilot-seo-score' in index.js. Until ember-cli v3.9, this error can be disabled by setting env variable EMBER_CLI_IGNORE_ADDON_NAME_MISMATCH to "true". For more information about this workaround, see: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/7950.`

My ember-cli version is `"ember-cli": "~3.28.3"`

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this in my addons:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: require('./package').name,
}
```

that way, they always match, even if renamed.

The issue is that your package.json name is `@copilot/copilot-seo-score`, but your name in index.js is `copilot-seo-score` and they need to match.